# Delete all entries which are not in "include" list

Tags: mysql

I have a column called "CustomerName" with text data.  I also have a list of Customer Names which I want to keep.  I want to execute a query that deletes the entire row of data if the CustomerName is not on my aforementioned keeper-list.

So basically I want to purge all the entries pertaining to customers not on my keeper-list.

Is there a way to do this in a single SQL query?

Comment: What database are you using?  Please tag appropriately.  What does the list look like?

Comment: `DELETE FROM ... WHERE CustomerName NOT IN (...)`

Comment: `EXISTS` or `IN`.

Comment: Do not use auto commit just in case...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would simply be:

```
delete t
     where t.customername not in (<list to keep>);
```

Comment: Thank you!  Still new to this.